# Node.js get fd file descriptor

Tags: node.js, fs, file-descriptor

Is fs.open/close the only way to get the file descriptor or is there a faster/efficient way?

The reason I close the file is cause I assume I should otherwise I'd end up leaving tones of files open.

```
fs.open('/my/file.txt','r',function(e,fd){
    console.log(fd);//12
    fs.close(fd,function(){
        fs.fsync(fd,function(){// more code ...
```

It seems a bit silly to open an close the file just to get an fd but fs.sync requires an fd (a number) instead of string.

Comment: What are you trying to do? File descriptors are only useful for opened files, just as `fs.sync` function.

Comment: force disk write for a database i'm making

Answer (score 0):

I can call close and don't wait for the callback

This way is Asynchronous (non-blocking)

```
fs.open('/my/file.txt','r',function(e,fd){
    console.log(fd);//12
    fs.close(fd,function(){});
    fs.fsync(fd,function(){// more code ...
```